# Twilio Send Message Method for Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, twilio

How do I fill in the send message method for Twilio, I know how to fill in the from, to and body. the only part that befuddles me is the System.Action. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Action is basicly a method.

You can call SendSmsMessage this way:

`Twilio.TwilioRestClient.SendSmsMessage("from", "to", "message", (smsmessage) => { });`

I'm not familiar with Twilio or the SendSmsMessage method, but I suspect, that this method gets called when SendSmsMessage finishes or something like that. In this case, `smsmessage` is a parameter that is usable in the Action.

You can read more about `System.Action` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and about c# lamdas in general [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Well I suspect that SendSmsMessage does not return anything, correct? (Maybe you could link to the twilio sdk you are using, I couldn't find it). SendSmsMessage is propably asynchronous which is the reason it returns void. When you look at the Action, the code in the `{ }`-brackets is propably being called, when the sms message was send and you can access the message via the `smsmessage`parameter.